# How to get dropdown menus behave like checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm a bit of a noob, but managed to make something still with the help of one JavaScript snippet I found here (need to dig it up soon, but for now, my problem:)

I'm making this website: [manu.mymaterial.org](https://manu.mymaterial.org) which **I wish would sort the images the same way with dropdown menus like it works now with the checkboxes**. I have tried and tried but nothing seems to work.

I have this prototype for you for fiddling out the problem, if you have the time. I would appreciate help immensely :)

I would like to be able to get same results with the **dropdown** menus (that **don't** work now) like with the **checkboxes** (that **do** work now)

https://codepen.io/manujarvinen/pen/BaRzGVa

Please tell me if I'm not clear enough or some information is missing. I'll be glad to get that info for you.

Cheers!

Manu

[gearnoodle.com](https://www.gearnoodle.com)

**EDIT:** The answer to this question is awesome! But even more polished answer came in here in my second question: [Filter accurately with BOTH checkboxes AND dropdown menus at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68317206/4383420) - Excellent!

---

Image of the [manu.mymaterial.org](https://manu.mymaterial.org) website, just to give you some context:

[image]

And this is how I would like it to be:

[image]

```js
var $filterCheckboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
var filterFunc = function() {

  var selectedFilters = [];

  $filterCheckboxes.filter(':checked').each(function() {
    var v = this.value;
    if (selectedFilters.indexOf(v) === -1)
        selectedFilters.push(v);
  });

  $('.animal' && '.filterDiv')
    .hide()
    .filter(
       function(_,a) {
          var itemCat = $(a).data('category').split(' ');
          return selectedFilters.every(
            function(c){
               return itemCat.indexOf(c) > -1;
            })
    })
    .show();

}

$filterCheckboxes.on('change', filterFunc);
```

```css
body {
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
background-color: black;
color: white;
}
.grid {
width: 300px;
margin: 50px auto;
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
.filterDiv {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Help needed in this URL: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68315184/4383420 -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<div class=grid>
    <select>
    <option value="showAll">show all</option>
    <option value="violet">violet</option>
    </select>
    <select>
    <option value="showAll">show all</option>
    <option value="blue">blue</option>
    </select>
    <select>
    <option value="showAll">show all</option>
    <option value="yellow">yellow</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class=grid>
    <label>violet
    <input type="checkbox" value="violet" />
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    <label>blue
    <input type="checkbox" value="blue" />
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    <label>yellow
    <input type="checkbox" value="yellow" />
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
</div>

<div class=grid>
    <div class="filterDiv" data-category="violet blue" style="background-color: blue"></div>
    <div class="filterDiv" data-category="violet red" style="background-color: red"></div>
    <div class="filterDiv" data-category="yellow" style="background-color: yellow"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You expect menu works same as checkbox so you don't need to `<option value="showAll">show all</option>`

simply you can get all `selected` option and doing like `filterFunc`

Here is working sample:

```js
 var $filterCheckboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
        var $filtermenues = $('.grid1');

        filterfuncAnother = function () {
            var selectedFilters = [];

            $filtermenues.find(":selected").each(function () {
                debugger
                var v = this.value;
                if (selectedFilters.indexOf(v) === -1 && v)
                    selectedFilters.push(v);
            });

            $('.animal' && '.filterDiv')
                .hide()
                .filter(
                    function (_, a) {
                        var itemCat = $(a).data('category').split(' ');
                        if (itemCat.indexOf("showAll") > -1)
                            return;
                        return selectedFilters.every(
                            function (c) {
                                return itemCat.indexOf(c) > -1;
                            })
                    })
                .show();
        }

        var filterFunc = function () {

            var selectedFilters = [];
            debugger
            $filterCheckboxes.filter(':checked').each(function () {
                var v = this.value;
                if (selectedFilters.indexOf(v) === -1)
                    selectedFilters.push(v);
            });

            $('.animal' && '.filterDiv')
                .hide()
                .filter(
                    function (_, a) {
                        var itemCat = $(a).data('category').split(' ');
                        return selectedFilters.every(
                            function (c) {
                                return itemCat.indexOf(c) > -1;
                            })
                    })
                .show();

        }

        $filterCheckboxes.on('change', filterFunc);

        $('select').on('change', filterfuncAnother);
```

```css
body {
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
background-color: black;
color: white;
}
.grid {
width: 300px;
margin: 50px auto;
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
.filterDiv {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Help needed in this URL: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68315184/4383420 -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <div class=grid1>
        <select>
            <option value="">--</option>
            <!--<option value="showAll">show all</option>-->
            <option value="violet">violet</option>
        </select>
        <select>
            <option value="">--</option>
            <!--<option value="showAll">show all</option>-->
            <option value="blue">blue</option>
        </select>
        <select>
            <option value="">--</option>
            <!--<option value="showAll">show all</option>-->
            <option value="yellow">yellow</option>
        </select>
    </div>

<div class=grid>
    <label>violet
    <input type="checkbox" value="violet" />
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    <label>blue
    <input type="checkbox" value="blue" />
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    <label>yellow
    <input type="checkbox" value="yellow" />
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
</div>

<div class=grid>
    <div class="filterDiv" data-category="violet blue" style="background-color: blue"></div>
    <div class="filterDiv" data-category="violet red" style="background-color: red"></div>
    <div class="filterDiv" data-category="yellow" style="background-color: yellow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! So cool :) I'll try out how this works out on my full website immediately ->
Thank you again!

Comment: I got a couple of problems with it still - even though it answered most of my problems. Just a little polish would be needed. I made a new question about it: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68317206/4383420 - I would really appreciate it if you had time. Cheers!