# Filter accurately with BOTH checkboxes AND dropdown menus at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm building a very sortable/filterable image gallery with a lot of tags.
This question is based upon this one [How to get dropdown menus behave like checkboxes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68315184) in where I got most of my problems answered.

EDIT: Here the finished code from this question is taken even further: [With a UNCHECKED checkbox, how to filter out NSFW tagged divs to be hidden at all times but when checked ON, to follow the visibility rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68334085/4383420)

But I thought that maybe you'd like to play a little **Debugging Game** to polish it even further :) Because the dropdown menus aren't playing perfectly with the checkboxes.

Here you go:
https://codepen.io/manujarvinen/pen/QWvEogb

And an image of it:
[image]

```js
var $filterCheckboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
       var $filtermenues = $('.grid1');

       filterfuncAnother = function () {
           var selectedFilters = [];

           $filtermenues.find(":selected").each(function () {
               debugger
               var v = this.value;
               if (selectedFilters.indexOf(v) === -1 && v)
                   selectedFilters.push(v);
           });

           $('.animal' && '.filterDiv')
               .hide()
               .filter(
                   function (_, a) {
                       var itemCat = $(a).data('category').split(' ');
                       if (itemCat.indexOf("showAll") > -1)
                           return;
                       return selectedFilters.every(
                           function (c) {
                               return itemCat.indexOf(c) > -1;
                           })
                   })
               .show();
       }

       var filterFunc = function () {

           var selectedFilters = [];
           debugger
           $filterCheckboxes.filter(':checked').each(function () {
               var v = this.value;
               if (selectedFilters.indexOf(v) === -1)
                   selectedFilters.push(v);
           });

           $('.animal' && '.filterDiv')
               .hide()
               .filter(
                   function (_, a) {
                       var itemCat = $(a).data('category').split(' ');
                       return selectedFilters.every(
                           function (c) {
                               return itemCat.indexOf(c) > -1;
                           })
                   })
               .show();

       }

       $filterCheckboxes.on('change', filterFunc);

       $('select').on('change', filterfuncAnother);
```

```css
body {
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
background-color: black;
color: white;
font-family: sans-serif;
}
.grid {
width: 300px;
margin: 50px auto;
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
.grid1 {
width: 300px;
margin: 50px auto;
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
.filterDiv {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
padding-top: 20px;
color: black;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!-- Based upon this URL: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68315184/4383420 -->

<!-- Help needed in this URL: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68317206/4383420 -->

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  DEBUGGING GAME!

   <div class=grid1>
          <select>
              <option value="">--</option>
              <option value="violet">violet</option>
          </select>
          <select>
              <option value="">--</option>
              <option value="blue">blue</option>
          </select>
          <select>
              <option value="">--</option>
              <option value="yellow">yellow</option>
          </select>
      </div>

  <div class=grid>
      <label>VIOLET
      <input type="checkbox" value="violet" />
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
      <label>BLUE
      <input type="checkbox" value="blue" />
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
      <label>YELLOW
      <input type="checkbox" value="yellow" />
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
  </div>

  <div class=grid>
      <div class="filterDiv" data-category="violet blue" style="background-color: blue">Tags: <br />violet <br />blue</div>
      <div class="filterDiv" data-category="violet red MVP" style="background-color: red">Tags: <br />violet <br />red <br />MVP</div>
      <div class="filterDiv" data-category="yellow" style="background-color: yellow">Tags: <br />yellow</div>
  </div>


  <div>
  <label>Most Valuable Player (MVP)
  <input type="checkbox" value="MVP" />
  <br />(ANY others than MVP shouldn't be seen at ALL times.<br />BUT it's okay for MVP to be hidden also, if rules aren't met.)
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>
  </div>

    <div style="width:400px; text-align: left; margin: 60px auto;">
    RULES:
    <p style="color:gray;">*Refresh*</p>
    <p>1. Turn ON MVP. Select BLUE from dropdown > ALL should be hidden.</p>
    <p style="color:gray;">*Refresh*</p>
    <p>2. Select YELLOW from dropdown. Turn on MVP > ALL should be hidden.</p>
    <p style="color:gray;">*Refresh*</p>
    <p>3. Turn ON MVP. Select YELLOW from dropdown > ALL should be hidden.</p>
    <p style="color:gray;">*Refresh*</p>
    <p>BONUS1: Turn ON MVP. Select YELLOW from dropdown. Turn OFF MVP > ONLY YELLOW should be seen.</p>
    <p style="color:gray;">*Refresh*</p>
    <p>BONUS2: Select YELLOW from dropdown. Check YELLOW CHECKBOX. Uncheck YELLOW CHECKBOX > ONLY YELLOW should be seen.</p>
      <p>CONGRATULATIONS!</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you expect.

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi Ah yes, sure. Well if these 5 issues were elegantly solved, the script would be perfect for the image gallery I’m making, which is mentioned in the other Question that I linked above. All that is needed is the dropdown menus mainly to follow the rules. In the gallery, if I only want to see motorcycle images, aeroplanes would disturb me if they appeared when expecting something different. Hope this clears things a bit :) Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want both elements to behave the same way, you probably want to set their behavior in the same function:

```js
var $filterCheckboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
       var $filtermenues = $('.grid1');


       var filterFunc = function () {

           var selectedFilters = [];
           $filtermenues.find(":selected").each(function () {
               
               var v = this.value;
               if (selectedFilters.indexOf(v) === -1 && v)
                   selectedFilters.push(v);
           });

           $('.animal' && '.filterDiv')
               .hide()
               .filter(
                   function (_, a) {
                       var itemCat = $(a).data('category').split(' ');
                       if (itemCat.indexOf("showAll") > -1)
                           return;
                       return selectedFilters.every(
                           function (c) {
                               return itemCat.indexOf(c) > -1;
                           })
                   })
               .show();
           $filterCheckboxes.filter(':checked').each(function () {
               var v = this.value;
               if (selectedFilters.indexOf(v) === -1)
                   selectedFilters.push(v);
           });

           $('.animal' && '.filterDiv')
               .hide()
               .filter(
                   function (_, a) {
                       var itemCat = $(a).data('category').split(' ');
                       return selectedFilters.every(
                           function (c) {
                               return itemCat.indexOf(c) > -1;
                           })
                   })
               .show();

       }

       $filterCheckboxes.on('change', filterFunc);

       $('select').on('change', filterFunc);
```

```css
body {
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
background-color: black;
color: white;
font-family: sans-serif;
}
.grid {
width: 300px;
margin: 50px auto;
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
.grid1 {
width: 300px;
margin: 50px auto;
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
.filterDiv {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
padding-top: 20px;
color: black;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!-- Based upon this URL: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68315184/4383420 -->

<!-- Help needed in this URL: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68317206/4383420 -->

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  DEBUGGING GAME!

   <div class=grid1>
          <select>
              <option value="">--</option>
              <option value="violet">violet</option>
          </select>
          <select>
              <option value="">--</option>
              <option value="blue">blue</option>
          </select>
          <select>
              <option value="">--</option>
              <option value="yellow">yellow</option>
          </select>
      </div>

  <div class=grid>
      <label>VIOLET
      <input type="checkbox" value="violet" />
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
      <label>BLUE
      <input type="checkbox" value="blue" />
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
      <label>YELLOW
      <input type="checkbox" value="yellow" />
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
  </div>

  <div class=grid>
      <div class="filterDiv" data-category="violet blue" style="background-color: blue">Tags: <br />violet <br />blue</div>
      <div class="filterDiv" data-category="violet red MVP" style="background-color: red">Tags: <br />violet <br />red <br />MVP</div>
      <div class="filterDiv" data-category="yellow" style="background-color: yellow">Tags: <br />yellow</div>
  </div>


  <div>
  <label>Most Valuable Player (MVP)
  <input type="checkbox" value="MVP" />
  <br />(ANY others than MVP shouldn't be seen at ALL times.<br />BUT it's okay for MVP to be hidden also, if rules aren't met.)
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>
  </div>

    <div style="width:400px; text-align: left; margin: 60px auto;">
    RULES:
    <p style="color:gray;">*Refresh*</p>
    <p>1. Turn ON MVP. Select BLUE from dropdown > ALL should be hidden.</p>
    <p style="color:gray;">*Refresh*</p>
    <p>2. Select YELLOW from dropdown. Turn on MVP > ALL should be hidden.</p>
    <p style="color:gray;">*Refresh*</p>
    <p>3. Turn ON MVP. Select YELLOW from dropdown > ALL should be hidden.</p>
    <p style="color:gray;">*Refresh*</p>
    <p>BONUS1: Turn ON MVP. Select YELLOW from dropdown. Turn OFF MVP > ONLY YELLOW should be seen.</p>
    <p style="color:gray;">*Refresh*</p>
    <p>BONUS2: Select YELLOW from dropdown. Check YELLOW CHECKBOX. Uncheck YELLOW CHECKBOX > ONLY YELLOW should be seen.</p>
      <p>CONGRATULATIONS!</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: OOOOOOooohh thank you thank you. I wouldn't had realized that in a million years! This seemed foolproof for me, exactly what I needed. Now, let me implement this to the real site :) Oooh yeah!