# With a UNCHECKED checkbox, how to filter out NSFW tagged divs to be hidden at all times but when checked ON, to follow the visibility rules?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

This question is based on this Question/Answer:
[Filter accurately with BOTH checkboxes AND dropdown menus at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68317206/4383420)

Hi!

(NOTE, the simplified question and code is in the codepen or the snippet below, here I'm just explaining the context.)

Image of the simplified question, for which I actually need the answer:
[image]

My reference image PHP gallery is progressing nicely: https://manu.mymaterial.org (Watch out, it includes NSFW material, Fine Art painting by Andrew Loomis, in the front page ATM.)

And that brings me to this question.

How can I have that "Display NSFW material" to NOT show ANY of the images that have the NSFW tag in them when the "Display NSFW material" checkbox is UNCHECKED, no matter what other filtering options I do?

I have a feeling that it is a simple if-statement in Javascript, but I'm uncertain where to put it exactly and if it breaks other things.

At the moment the NSFW checkbox displays ONLY the NSFW material (yellow box) and nothing else. This is not desired.

So, in other words, I have tags for all of the material to be shown in various ways - but now the NSFW tag should HIDE stuff when included into a div. Or in my case, it's just an image file that gets processed by PHP and into a div: Andrew_Loomis; Traditional_Characters_Realistic_Color_**NSFW**.jpg

Codepen project:
https://codepen.io/manujarvinen/pen/wvdzeQv

Thank you all, this is a fine place.

Image of my project thing:
[image]

```js
var $filterCheckboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
       var $filtermenues = $('.grid1');


       var filterFunc = function () {

           var selectedFilters = [];
           $filtermenues.find(":selected").each(function () {
               
               var v = this.value;
               if (selectedFilters.indexOf(v) === -1 && v)
                   selectedFilters.push(v);
           });

           $('.animal' && '.filterDiv')
               .hide()
               .filter(
                   function (_, a) {
                       var itemCat = $(a).data('category').split(' ');
                       if (itemCat.indexOf("showAll") > -1)
                           return;
                       return selectedFilters.every(
                           function (c) {
                               return itemCat.indexOf(c) > -1;
                           })
                   })
               .show();
           $filterCheckboxes.filter(':checked').each(function () {
               var v = this.value;
               if (selectedFilters.indexOf(v) === -1)
                   selectedFilters.push(v);
           });

           $('.animal' && '.filterDiv')
               .hide()
               .filter(
                   function (_, a) {
                       var itemCat = $(a).data('category').split(' ');
                       return selectedFilters.every(
                           function (c) {
                               return itemCat.indexOf(c) > -1;
                           })
                   })
               .show();

       }

       $filterCheckboxes.on('change', filterFunc);

       $('select').on('change', filterFunc);
```

```css
body {
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
background-color: black;
color: white;
font-family: sans-serif;
}
.grid {
width: 300px;
margin: 50px auto;
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
.grid1 {
width: 300px;
margin: 50px auto;
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
.filterDiv {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
padding-top: 20px;
color: black;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!-- Help needed in this URL: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68334085/4383420 -->

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <div class=grid1>
          <select>
              <option value="">--</option>
              <option value="violet">violet</option>
          </select>
          <select>
              <option value="">--</option>
              <option value="blue">blue</option>
          </select>
          <select>
              <option value="">--</option>
              <option value="yellow">yellow</option>
          </select>
      </div>

  <div class=grid>
      <label>VIOLET
      <input type="checkbox" value="violet" />
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
      <label>BLUE
      <input type="checkbox" value="blue" />
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
      <label>YELLOW
      <input type="checkbox" value="yellow" />
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
  </div>

  <div class=grid>
      <div class="filterDiv" data-category="violet blue" style="background-color: blue">Tags: <br />violet <br />blue</div>
      <div class="filterDiv" data-category="violet red MVP" style="background-color: red">Tags: <br />violet <br />red <br />MVP</div>
      <div class="filterDiv" data-category="yellow NSFW MVP" style="background-color: yellow">Tags: <br />yellow <br />NSFW<br />MVP</div>
  </div>


  <div>
  <label>Most Valuable Players (MVP)
  <input type="checkbox" value="MVP" />
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>
  </div>

  <div>
  <label>Display NSFW material also
  <input type="checkbox" value="NSFW" />
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>
  </div>

    <div style="width:400px; text-align: left; margin: 60px auto;">
    What I need:
    
    <p>By default, NSFW material checkbox is OFF and YELLOW shouldn't be seen at all in ANY situation.</p>
      <p>When NSFW material checkbox is checked, ALSO YELLOW should be seen, but follow rest of the rules.</p>
      
      
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is overly complex, and hard to follow. For one, this bit

```js
        var v = this.value;
        if (selectedFilters.indexOf(v) === -1 && v)
            selectedFilters.push(v);
```

merely serves to avoid duplicates in the array. This means that it is more like a [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), which is a data structure that avoids duplicates by itself. If you do `selectedFilters = new Set()`, then that entire block can be replaced by `selectedFilters.add(this.value);`

Queries "is this category contained in the selected filters" can then also be reduced from `selectedFilters.indexOf(cat) === -1` to `selectedFilters.has(cat)`. That way the code already starts to match much more the desired behaviour.

Furthermore, the single-letter variables should also be abolished, and be replaced by explanatory names. The code should also have more comments to explain what's going on.

Then there is the confusion of being able to select filters from both the menu and the checkboxes. I'm not sure how this should work, so I've just changed the code such that it groups them all together: a filter is active when it's either selected by the checkbox or the menu.

Finally there is the problem that the "NSFW allowed" is not really the same as filtering of the other categories. Because of that, I just created a separate variable for it, and removed it from the filter. And finally finally I added an extra call to `filterFunc()` so that things start out filtered (instead of waiting for the first change to the filter checkboxes/menus). This is the end result.

**EDIT:** Updated for the "MVP only" checkbox.

**EDIT 2:** Don't let the "MVP" checkbox show everything with the MVP tag.

**EDIT 3:** Flipped the condition to show items; they need all the tags now. The old code is left commented-out, so that anyone can revert this switch for themselves if they want.

```js
var $filterCheckboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
var $filtermenus = $('.grid1');


// Return the intersection of setA and setB.
// Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set
function intersection(setA, setB) {
    let _intersection = new Set()
    for (let elem of setB) {
        if (setA.has(elem)) {
            _intersection.add(elem)
        }
    }
    return _intersection
}
function isSuperset(set, subset) {
    for (let elem of subset) {
        if (!set.has(elem)) {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}


function filterFunc() {
    var selectedFilters = new Set();

    // Gather tags from the menus.
    $filtermenus.find(":selected").each(function () {
        if (this.value)
            selectedFilters.add(this.value);
    });
    // Gather tags from the checkboxes.
    $filterCheckboxes.filter(':checked').each(function () {
        if (this.value)
            selectedFilters.add(this.value);
    });
    console.log("selected filters:", [...selectedFilters]);
 
    let mayShowNSFW = selectedFilters.has("NSFW");
    selectedFilters.delete("NSFW");
  
    let mustShowMVPOnly = selectedFilters.has("MVP");
    selectedFilters.delete("MVP");

    $('.filterDiv')
        .hide()
        .filter(
            // Returns 'true' to show items, 'false' to hide them.
            function (_, element) {
                let itemCats = new Set($(element).data('category').split(' '));

                // If the item has tag 'showAll', always show it.
                if (itemCats.has("showAll"))
                    return true;
                
                // If item is NSFW but that's not in the filters, hide the item
                // regardless of other tags.
                if (itemCats.has("NSFW") && !mayShowNSFW)
                    return false;
                
                if (mustShowMVPOnly && !itemCats.has("MVP"))
                    return false;
                
                // If there are no filters at all, just show everything.
                if (selectedFilters.size == 0)
                    return true;

                // If this item has all the tags, show it:
                return isSuperset(itemCats, selectedFilters);
              
                // If this item has any of the tags, show it:
                // return intersection(selectedFilters, itemCats).size > 0;
            })
        .show();
}

$filterCheckboxes.on('change', filterFunc);
$('select').on('change', filterFunc);
filterFunc();
```

Comment: Yay! This is perfect - - - - Except of course I forgot to emphasize the fact that BLUE should not be seen when the MVP checkbox is ON. MVP was meant to be for only for certain kinds of blocks who have that MVP tag and everything else should be hidden. Here's a new easy CodePen project with your latest code in it:
https://codepen.io/manujarvinen/pen/eYWdbVM 

- I truly hope the change in the code would be just a minor addition, not to burden you too much! Thank you always whatever you decide to do! :)

Comment: Yay! The MVP feature and NSFW feature work now very nicely! - - - But dang it, I hate to be such a drag, there's still one thing. Color tags should dictate over even the MVP tag. - Here's the CodePen with your latest code: https://codepen.io/manujarvinen/pen/vYmXzYP - it should be a very minor fix somewhere. I even made a diagram, but I don't know if it helps or complicates things: https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1UCpzl6KIoTC_evI0oe7NOaZm3fGrT-JaZMtsiOpWKI0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Argh, sorry, the diagram truly complicates things, I'll change it a bit but feel free to ignore it. The most important thing is in the codepen link. I can imagine planning a software development project with multiple employees must be HARD

Comment: Well that's simple, in that case MVP doesn't play along as a normal tag. Add `selectedFilters.delete("MVP");` and it'll work. I'll update the answer for this.

Comment: This is so great! Thanks again. With this current code, and knowing how the code behaves if there is not that `selectedFilters.delete("MVP");` line I have the possibility to add that functionality to the site maybe later if needed :) Excellent excellent.

Comment: Tested it, works nicely :) But STILL one issue: I believe that what I need is SUBTRACTIVE filtering, but what you have is ADDITIVE filtering, at least this is my hunch. The red texts explain what is needed. The old version worked exactly like it should.
- Before your help: https://codepen.io/manujarvinen/pen/vYmXoQE - Current code of yours: https://codepen.io/manujarvinen/pen/poPEMBa
- As always, thank you for any time you give for this :)

Comment: That's just a matter of changing the last condition.

Comment: Awww yes, isSUPERset, but of course... lol.. I wouldn't have guessed in a million years. But wonderful it was an easy thing! -> Testing
- Thank you again!! :)

Comment: Beautiful, works like a perfect clockwork! Here it is in action: https://manu.mymaterial.org (and NSFW material naturally hidden from the startup, like you coded :) Yeehaa! Thanks for being patient with me.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this in your css stylesheet

```css
.nsfw{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

And this should be in the head tag of your html page

```html
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#nsfw').change(function () {
                if (!this.checked)
                    //  ^
                    $('.nsfw').css('visibility', 'hidden');
                else
                    $('.nsfw').css('visibility', 'visible');
            });
        });
</script>
```

Your nsfw box should be something like this

```html
<div class="filterDiv nsfw" data-category="yellow NSFW MVP" style="background-color: yellow">Tags: <br />yellow
            <br />NSFW<br />MVP
</div>
```

Here is the checkbox

```html
<div>
        <label>Display NSFW material also
            <input type="checkbox" value="NSFW" id="nsfw" />
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
```

Comment: I just love how elegantly easy this is to understand for someone like me! :) Thank you! - With PHP it should be easy-peasy to add the extra class to NSFW divs. I shall test thoroughly both this and Dr.Sybren's code for sure!

Comment: Thank you so much for this, it does almost exactly how it should go, sorry if I explained it badly in the question :/  - --- https://codepen.io/manujarvinen/pen/yLbaWzG <- CodePen of your code. There's one thing: "when I click "Display NSFW material also"-checkbox, it hides all the rest than the YELLOW box. That's not desired. The checkbox should only affect the visibility rules of the YELLOW box, not others :/

Comment: i think there's some problem in here cuz at my end it worked perfectly

Comment: i'll try to solve ur problem as soon as possible

Comment: Thank you! - Even though, now I'll try the Dr. Sybren's code, let's see how it performs :)

Answer (score 0):

You can give a class to all nsfw images and then set their visibility to hidden in css. and when checkbox is checked you can set nsfw images visibility to hidden.

Comment: Thanks for the comment!
I'm trying my best to poke the code. Let's see if I can make it to work...

Comment: i can help you with css but i can't sort of understand your javascript code can you please tell how are you checking if the checkbox is ticked or not ?

Comment: It's so sophisticated code I also don't understand it... javascript is not my cup of tea :/ ... so I had some help which was nice.

However, with PHP I can crank the NSFW tags from the filename to give the needed css class for the div. The thing is, yes, how to ...control the checking and unchecking... dang it

Comment: i can help you with checking too 

Comment: Well, whatever works to get the thing to work :P - I'm trying to solve this with PHP at the moment but I'm such a tool, let's see how this goes

Comment: you can give an id to the nsfw checkbox and then use use a let nsVal = document.getElementById("nsfw") and then in an if statement use nsVal.checked then give or remove the classes from all the elements

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234740/discussion-between-om-nigam-and-manu-jarvinen).

Comment: please check the chat

Comment: Yes! Heading home now, so, in 15mins! :)